# java web application architecture, many war's inside an ear or one war with many jars

Tags: java, jsp, maven, jakarta-ee, tomcat

I need to build a web application for example, approximately 1 \ 2 months of work, while for the server side I have quite clear ideas, for the front-end I have some doubts ..

The application will be modular and will contain 4 sub-projects (maven) ...

As a sample application, I was wondering if it was more convenient\easy to define the logic of the back-end in different modules (packaged as jar) and a single component containing the front-end (jsp's), compress finally all in one war.

Or instead create different maven modules each with its own front-end part and his war and then finally use a container such as ear ..

I think the second choice would definitely be more accurate, but also more complex, as the first choice is not correct, it is easier to implement ..

What do you advise me? can you clarify a little my ideas?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It is recommended to use the second approach with multiple poms. You can use one common pom.xml like superpom which will include all other poms . This will be helpful for ease of deployment and modules .